# How can I compute the size of my Linux install + all my applications?

Tags: linux, ssd

I don't have a separate / and /home partition, but I would want to know how much HDD space my system, applications and all of the configs take up?

I am asking because I might buy a very cheap SSD, but I am worried about the space constraints because I don't want to have to worry about space constraints when downloading a lot of stuff from the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `df -h /` and note the space used.  Then, as root, run `du -sh /home`.  Subtract the second figure from the first.  This gives you the amount used by the root filesystem, less any space consumed by /home.

Bear in mind you may have a swap volume using disk space too.

Comment: AFAIK putting swap on SSD may decrease its lifetime noticeably

Comment: Oh yeah, I should never put swap on SSD... I even have full disk encryption and I am not sure if that is good for an SSD.

Comment: This will give a good rough estimate, but will overstate the size of install+applications: various temporary-file collections (`/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, `/run`, etc.) and possibly virtual filesystems (`/sys`, `/proc`, etc.) will be included in the total.